# Fastest way of computing binary mask IOU with numpy

Tags: numpy, optimization

I'm looking for the fastest way to compute the intersection over union (Jaccard Index) of two binary masks (2d arrays of 1s and 0s) in numpy of the exact same shape. My code for computing this is:

```
import numpy as np

def binaryMaskIOU(mask1, mask2):
    mask1_area = np.count_nonzero(mask1 == 1)
    mask2_area = np.count_nonzero(mask2 == 1)
    intersection = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(mask1==1,  mask2==1))
    iou = intersection/(mask1_area+mask2_area-intersection)
    return iou
```

So I have two arrays with only 1s and zeros (a binary image mask), and:

- the area of each mask is the number of 1s in the array
- the intersection of both masks is the spatial locations where both masks are equal to 1
- the IOU (intersection over union) is defined as the intersection divided by the union

Any optimization hints/insights appreciated as in my code I need to run this operation many times with large numbers of masks and I want to make sure it is as fast as possible.

Comment: The intersection calculated in the function is to count where `mask1 == mask2`, i.e where they are both one or both zero.  Is this what you meant?  In the text the intersection says count where they are both ones.

Comment: @TlsChris good point, will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initialy posted an answer, realised I'd over complicated it and when I went to edit it found the timings were worse than the original function.  That's been deleted.

The code in the question performs close to the others.
There's no need for the two `maskN == 1` in the `logical_and`.

The dtype can have a significant effect.  `bm1` is much faster If it's np.bool but it depends what else is being done with the data.

If it's possible to change the dtype there may be some significant time savings otherwise I can't see much, perhaps somebody else can.

```
import numpy as np

def make_arrays( size = ( 5,5 ), dtype = np.int ):
    return ( np.random.randint( 2, size = size, dtype = dtype ),
             np.random.randint( 2, size = size, dtype = dtype ) )

def bm0(mask1, mask2):
    mask1_area = np.count_nonzero(mask1 == 1)       # I assume this is faster as mask1 == 1 is a bool array
    mask2_area = np.count_nonzero(mask2 == 1)
    intersection = np.count_nonzero( np.logical_and( mask1, mask2) )
    iou = intersection/(mask1_area+mask2_area-intersection)
    return iou

def bm1(mask1, mask2):
    mask1_area = np.count_nonzero( mask1 )
    mask2_area = np.count_nonzero( mask2 )
    intersection = np.count_nonzero( np.logical_and( mask1, mask2 ) )
    iou = intersection/(mask1_area+mask2_area-intersection)
    return iou

def binaryMaskIOU(mask1, mask2):   # From the question.
    mask1_area = np.count_nonzero(mask1 == 1)
    mask2_area = np.count_nonzero(mask2 == 1)
    intersection = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and( mask1==1,  mask2==1 ))
    iou = intersection/(mask1_area+mask2_area-intersection)
    return iou


n = 50
a, b = make_arrays( ( n, n ) )

bm0( a, b )
# 0.3416313559322034

bm1(a,b)
# 0.3416313559322034

binaryMaskIOU(a,b)
# 0.3416313559322034

%timeit bm0( a, b )
#  7.73 µs ± 22.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit bm1( a, b )
# 12.2 µs ± 20.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit binaryMaskIOU( a, b )
# 10.3 µs ± 36.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

n = 500
a, b = make_arrays( ( n, n ) )

%timeit bm0( a, b )
#  342 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit bm1( a, b )
# 1.01 ms ± 514 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit binaryMaskIOU( a, b )
#  419 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#################  make a and b np.bool arrays  #################
n = 500
a, b = make_arrays( ( n, n), dtype = np.bool )

%timeit bm0( a, b )
# 439 µs ± 406 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit bm1( a, b )
#  63.2 µs ± 174 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit binaryMaskIOU( a, b )
# 814 µs ± 496 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I guess I am wondering now what the tradeoff will be to convert my arrays to np.bool and then run these computations. Well thanks for the benchmarks!

Answer (score 1):

Optionally you can use Pytorch using cuda (GPU). This turns out to be much faster than using numpy.

I used this code in a Kaggle competition to compute IOU and in terms of speed much better than numpy:

```
def iou(mask1, mask2):
    intersection = (mask1 * mask2).sum()
    if intersection == 0:
        return 0.0
    union = torch.logical_or(mask1, mask2).to(torch.int).sum()
    return intersection / union
```

Answer (score 0):

I should add that the original context of this is to compute the average precision of a Mask R-CNN architecture's output on an instance segmentation testing dataset. For this reason the masks are pytorch tensors on the gpu, so I do have to send them to the cpu, and then to numpy, and then compute the binaryMaskIOU output as in the above.

Alternatively here is a snippet very similar to the numpy code for pytorch tensor mask iou

```
def binaryMaskIOU_(mask1, mask2):
    mask1_area = torch.count_nonzero(mask1)
    mask2_area = torch.count_nonzero(mask2)
    intersection = torch.count_nonzero(torch.logical_and(mask1, mask2))
    iou = intersection / (mask1_area + mask2_area - intersection)
    return iou
```

The average time is faster than numpy, as exhibited by this code

```
time_counter = 0.0
for i in range(10000):
    mask1 = torch.randint(0, 2, (800, 800)).cuda()
    mask2 = torch.randint(0, 2, (800, 800)).cuda()
    t1 = time.time()
    iou = binaryMaskIOU_(mask1, mask2)
    t2 = time.time()
    time_counter += t2-t1
average_time = time_counter / 10000
print("The average time for numpy mask iou is " + str(average_time))
```

with output  0.0007... as compared to 0.003 for the numpy equivalent.